# CommonCrypto in iOS producing different results to Rijndael in C#

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

Right, so I have an API I'm trying to pass a password to. I need to send the password as an encrypted AES 256 string. I've got a working implementation of this process written in C# using Rijndael. This is as follows:

```
AESKey.Text = "WebServices_TestKeyT218adje2s83a"; 
UniqueIV.Text = "T6wfOZgP0Q1uq0gaEHo8ww==";  
pwd1.Text = @"test12";

ASCIIEncoding textConverter = new ASCIIEncoding(); 
// Pad entered password to multiple of 16 
int padLen = 16 - (pwd1.TextLength % 16);

count1.Text = Convert.ToString(padLen);

int totalWidth = pwd1.TextLength + padLen; 
string paddedpwd = pwd1.Text.PadRight(totalWidth, (char)21);

byte[] password = textConverter.GetBytes(pwd1.Text.PadRight(totalWidth, (char)padLen));

// Decode entered IV 
byte[] decodedIV = Convert.FromBase64String(UniqueIV.Text);

string DecodedIVString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedIV);

byte[] aeskey1 = textConverter.GetBytes(AESKey.Text);

string AESKeyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(aeskey1);

//string aeskey = AESKey.Text;

// Create a new Rijndael object 
RijndaelManaged rij = new RijndaelManaged();

// Set a few starting bits... 
rij.IV = decodedIV; 
rij.Key = aeskey1; 
rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

// Generate encryptor... 
ICryptoTransform encryptor = rij.CreateEncryptor();


// Memory to hold encrypted data... 
byte[] encPassword = null;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
{ 
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) 
    { 
        cs.Write(password, 0, password.Length); 

        encPassword = new byte[ms.Length]; 
        encPassword = ms.ToArray(); 
    } 
}

// Encode enrypted password 
string encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(encPassword);

EncodedPasswordBox.Text = encodedPassword;
```

This works, and outputs:

```
V0xd7lMUWfJjlWpXJKzjPw==
```

which is accepted by the web service no problem. I tried to replicate this process in Objective-C. The first method takes the password and does the padding etc. and then calls encryption method:

```
NSString * Password = @"test12";

int padding = 16 - ([Password length] % 16);

int asciiCode = padding;

for(int i=0;i<padding;i++)
{
    Password = [Password stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", asciiCode]];
}

NSLog(@"Password after padding: %@", Password);

NSLog(@"Padding: %d", padding);

NSString *base64EncodedString = [[Password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"Encoded Padded PWD: %@", base64EncodedString);

NSString * IVString = @"T6wfOZgP0Q1uq0gaEHo8ww==";
NSData * IVData = [self base64DecodeString:IVString];

NSLog(@"IVData: %@", IVData);

NSString * decodedIV = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:IVData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Decoded IV: %@", decodedIV);

NSData * CryptoPass = [self AES256Encryptor1:Password WithKey:@"WebServices_TestKeyT218adje2s83a" iv:decodedIV];

NSString * Pass1 = [self base64EncodeData:CryptoPass];

NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CryptoPass encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Cryptopass B64: %@", Pass1);

NSLog(@"Cryptopass: %@", CryptoPass);
```

The IV, the Key and the password are all identical to those used in the C# example. Heres the Encryption Method:

```
- (NSData *)AES256Encryptor1:(NSString *)dataString WithKey:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv {

// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"keyPtr: '%s'", keyPtr);

NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"keyPtr: '%s'", keyData.bytes);
NSData *dataToEncrypt = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *ivData = [iv dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [dataToEncrypt length];
NSLog(@"Data length: %d", dataLength);

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;

NSLog(@"Buffer Size: %zu", bufferSize);

void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0,
                                      keyData.bytes, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      ivData.bytes, // initialisation vector
                                      dataToEncrypt.bytes,
                                      dataToEncrypt.length, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %d", cryptStatus);
}

free(buffer); //free the buffer;
return nil;
}
```

But this returns something completely different to the C#. I get the following base 64 string:

```
faAoHJ/oBGVpi0LHi6fhzrWMT9+z/uqYm1bdHOKrs6o=
```

Now, obviously this is completely the wrong length. I'm wondering if Common Crypto is appending an extra block? It's using a buffer size of 32 but I have no idea if this is right.

If somebody could please provide some advice as to wether I've done something stupid and possibly provide me with a solution or some inkling as to how to reach one that would be really helpful!

Thanks!

Adam

**EDIT:**

As requested in one of the comments below, here are the appropriate outputs from each example:

keyData (keyPTR) (Obj-C): WebServices_TestKeyT218adje2s83a

DataToEncrypt (Obj-C): <6164616d 31320a0a 0a0a0a0a 0a0a0a0a>

DataToEncrypt (C#): 6164616d31320a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a

IVData (Obj-C): <4fac1f39 980fd10d 6eab481a 107a3cc3>

IVData (C#): 4fac1f39980fd10d6eab481a107a3cc3

All the values are the same in both Obj-C and C# pre-encryption. I made sure I got this right before I started trying to encrypt anything so it should have all the right inputs.

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to the commenter Zaph below for pointing out that I had padding specified in Obj-C but not in C#, I now have a string thats the right length. When I run it now I get the string:

MO8yM8RSN+xEBV6/r6Mx5A==

The string in C# is: V0xd7lMUWfJjlWpXJKzjPw==

Comment: I don't see that the C# version has padding specified, is that a default and does it use PKCS7Padding?

Comment: Very good point! I've changed this to 0 in the Obj-C and now I have a string of the right length! It's still not the right string, but it is now a valid length! I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: The data length is always 16 and the block size is 32 so that should be fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved it!

Thanks so much to Zaph, the commenter on the original question for pointing me down the right path with regards to PKCS7Padding.

The issue was a simple one, although it took some figuring out on my part. I was passing in the string of the decoded IV rather then the data as in the original C# example. The piece of code at fault was:

```
NSString * decodedIV = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:IVData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

and then:

```
NSData * CryptoPass = [self AES256Encryptor1:Password WithKey:@"key" iv:decodedIV];
```

where as the first line shouldn't have existed and I should have instead just passed IVData straight in as so:

```
NSData * CryptoPass = [self AES256Encryptor1:Password WithKey:@"key" iv:IVData];
```

and modified the encryption method as follows:

```
- (NSData *)AES256Encryptor1:(NSString *)dataString WithKey:(NSString *)key iv:(NSData *)iv {

// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"keyPtr: '%s'", keyPtr);

NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"keyPtr: '%s'", keyData.bytes);
NSData *dataToEncrypt = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Data To Encrypt: %@", dataToEncrypt);
NSData *ivData = iv;

NSUInteger dataLength = [dataToEncrypt length];
NSLog(@"Data length: %d", dataLength);

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
//   size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;

NSLog(@"Buffer Size: %zu", bufferSize);

void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0,
                                      keyData.bytes, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      ivData.bytes, // initialisation vector
                                      dataToEncrypt.bytes,
                                      dataToEncrypt.length, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %d", cryptStatus);
}

free(buffer); //free the buffer;
return nil;
}
```

So, I hope this helps somebody else out because it's caused me a bit of a headache!

Thanks!

Adam

Comment: Do you have decryption solution in iOS ? Current I have c# encrypted string, but I have a trouble decrypting it in iOS. And I was stuck for several days.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the NSLog output for keyData, dataToEncrypt, ivData or the data to be returned. Are they the same as the C# values? Please add this output to your question. Separate the operation into three pieces for debugging: preparing the inputs to the decryption, the decryption, post processing the results. Then the focus can be applied to the code that is performing incorrectly.

I don't see that the C# version has padding specified, is that a default and does it use PKCS7Padding?

If you don't specify padding the data must be an exact multiple of the block size.

Check the key data with a data dump, not a character dump. NSLog(@"keyData: %@", keyData); Usually 'NSUTF8StringEncoding ` is used rather than NSASCIIStringEncoding.